# Using Jenkins parameter to call python file via batch command

Tags: jenkins, parameters, jenkins-pipeline

I am struggling with a Jenkins pipeline and hope you can help me out.
I need a Jenkins parameter (**Cycle**) within a batch command to call a python script.

```
environment {
    Variant = "${params.Var}"
    Cycle = "2021"
}
stages {
    stage('Check for most recent project') { 
        steps {
            script{
                if ("${Variant}" == "green") { 
                    help = bat(script: 'python.exe "somescript.py" --sourcepath \"\\Buildenv\\green\\${Cycle}\"', returnStdout: true)
                }
                else {
                    help = bat(script: 'python.exe "somescript.py" --sourcepath \"\\Buildenv\\red\\${Cycle}\"', returnStdout: true)
                }
                ProjectToBuild = help.split('\n')[-1]
                if ("${Variant}" == "green") {
                    bat script: "copy \"\\Buildenv\\green\\${Cycle}\\${ProjectToBuild}.7z\" \"D:\\Workspace\""  
                }
                else {
                    bat script: "copy \"\\Buildenv\\red\\${Cycle}\\${ProjectToBuild}.7z\" \"D:\\Workspace\""  
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In a pure batch command (bottom lines) using a parameter works perfectly fine. However, if I am calling a python script and want to handover a parameter this doesn't work.
Unfortunately I didn't find any post helping me with this.

Thanks for your help already!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is not related to python execution, it is related to the fact that in groovy single quotes (`' '`) don't support [String Interpolation](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation) only double quotes (`" "`) do, and therefore your parameter is not getting evaluated.
So you have two options:

1. Change your `bat` script so it uses double quotes:

```
help = bat(script: "python.exe \"somescript.py\" --sourcepath \"\\Buildenv\\green\\${Cycle}\"", returnStdout: true)
```

2. Because `Cycle` is set as an environment parameter it is passed to the command line environment and you can use it as a Windows environment variable with `% %`:

```
help = bat(script: 'python.exe "somescript.py" --sourcepath "\\Buildenv\\green\\%Cycle%"', returnStdout: true)
```

Comment: Awesome! Took me ages to play around and still didn't get to a conclusion. The "environment parameter" was one of my most recent attempts...but seems I did it somehow wrong. Works now tho!